# Necessary condition for symmetric sums

Tags: combinatorics, summation, symmetric-polynomials

It is easy to see that if a function $f(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ can be written in the form:
$$
f(x_1,x_2,x_3) = g(x_1,x_2) - g(x_1,x_3) + g(x_2,x_3)
$$

for some function $g$, then we have:
$$
f(x_1,x_2,x_3) - f(x_1,x_2,x_4) + f(x_1,x_3,x_4) - f(x_2,x_3,x_4) =0.
$$
Only if this last equation is satisfied there is the possibility that $f$ can be written in the form above.

Suppose instead that we look for a function $f$ in the form: 
$$
f(x_1,x_2,x_3) = g(x_1,x_2) + g(x_1,x_3) + g(x_2,x_3).
$$

Can we find a necessary condition for $f$ in a similar way? 
Can it be done for symmetric sums in arbitrary dimensions?

Thank you.

**(Please help me finding appropriate tags, feel free to edit!)**

Comment: Well clearly one requirement is $f(x_{\sigma(1)},x_{\sigma(2)},x_{\sigma(3)}) = f(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ for every $\sigma \in S_3$, and the same is true for any other 'symmetric' sum by definition. 

But the two examples you give are fundamentally different. The examples with the alternating signs are closely related to homology theory, and the fact that $\partial^2=0$ for the boundary map $\partial$.

Comment: Yes, precisely! Now the first and the second equation look similar, as they are both "boundaries". 
Here I don't need something like $\partial^2=0$, the sufficient condition could look very different from the symmetric sum.

Comment: Are you assuming $g(x,y)$ is a polynomial, and symmetric in $x,y$?  If so, a necessary and sufficient is that there are no terms in $f(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ with a factor of $x_1x_2x_3$.  Put another way, $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_2} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_3} f = 0$.